# How do you manage the variation between local and cloud dependencies within Docker?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a Docker image with an application server running in it.

When I'm running in a development environment, I want to run a database server within the same Docker image.

However, in production, I want to use my cloud provider's database service to host my database server.

What is the best (preferably officially supported) way to enable this distinction?

Comment: The best way is: _don't_. Don't run multiple things, particularly not including services like databases, in one container. Then there's no variation, the container just gets a connection string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, thanks! Should I then have two separate containers — one the application server and the other the database server — and I can just run both in development and only one in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Don't

You don't run the DB in the same container. You run it in a separate container next to your application container (Probably with docker-compose, but not required)

You run the same version as the cloud provider (or as close as you can get because they will no doubt configure it specifically for their env)